# github nkzawa msocket not connecting when app is working with another domain to login

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, android-notifications, background-service

I am building an app which will listen to a socket port(http://example:3000) for notification. I am using it as Background Service.
When my baseurl for all the json operation for app is also http://example.com/.. its working fine.
But if I change the base url to http://example2.in/ which has same and structure like the other and hits the same node port, msocekt does not connect.
please help anyone.

```java
package com.NativeAndroid.Services;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.NativeAndroid.MyNotification;
import com.NativeAndroid.R;
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

public class BackgroundNodeService extends IntentService {

    public static String REQUEST_ACCEPT = "yes";

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            //mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.203:3000");
            mSocket = IO.socket("https://example.com:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "instance initializer: Error Connecting");
        }
    }

    public BackgroundNodeService() {
        super("BackgroundNodeService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //mSocket.connect();
//        mSocket.open();
        mSocket.on("news", onNewMessage);
        mSocket.io();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String s = intent.getStringExtra("stop");
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: Intent: "+s);
        if (s !=null && s.equals("1")){
            if (mSocket.connected()){
                mSocket.disconnect();
                mSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: Socket Closed");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: Socekt is not connected");
            }
        } else {

            if (mSocket.connected()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: connected");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: not connected");

                mSocket.connect();
                mSocket.open();
                //mSocket.close();
            }
        }

        //Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ");
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {

            Log.d(TAG, "call: "+args[0]);
            String s = args[0].toString();
            showNotification(args[0]);

        }
    };

    private void showNotification(Object arg) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Log.d(TAG, "showNotification: "+arg);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) arg;
        try {
            String name = jsonObject.getString("title");
            String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");
            JSONObject body = new JSONObject(msg);
            String database_recodr = body.getString("database_recodr");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(database_recodr).getJSONObject("data");

            String title = obj.getString("title");
            String msgBody = obj.getString("body");
            String image = obj.getString("image");
            String pushFlag = obj.getString("push_flag");
            bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(image);
            Log.d(TAG, "showNotification: body"+body);
            Log.d(TAG, "showNotification: obj"+obj);
            //Log.d(TAG, "call: "+name+msg);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilabhra";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel =new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"My Notification",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                );
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Nialbhra");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                //notificationChannel.setLightColor(android.support.v4.R.color.notification_icon_bg_color);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);

                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNotification.class);
            intent.putExtra("testkey","hi");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

            if (bitmap != null){
                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notiicon)
//                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.support.loader.R.drawable.notification_bg))
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlelogo))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap))
                        .setContentText(msgBody)
                        .setContentInfo("Info")
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            } else {
                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notiicon)
//                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.support.loader.R.drawable.notification_bg))
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlelogo))
                        .setContentText(msgBody)
                        .setContentInfo("Info")
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            }

            notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());

            LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            Intent updateUiintent = new Intent(REQUEST_ACCEPT);
            updateUiintent.putExtra("noification_came", "yes");
            updateUiintent.putExtra("title", title);
            updateUiintent.putExtra("flag_check",pushFlag);
            updateUiintent.putExtra("image",image);
            broadcaster.sendBroadcast(updateUiintent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    public void closeConnection(){

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onDestroy() {
//
//    }
}
```

Comment: Ther is another file where my baseulr for all app related work is comming.

Comment: `public class ConfigDetails {
    //public static String MAIN_BASE_API_URL = "https://www.example.com/push_notification_management/";

    public static String MAIN_BASE_API_URL = "https://www.example2.in/push_notification_management/";
}`